# Preview long concatinated String in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

How can I preview a long string (SQL query), for example (code actual to Android development in Eclipse Juno):

```
String insert_reminder = "INSERT INTO REMINDERS (NAME, DESCRIPTION, REMIND_TIMESTAMP, REMIND_TYPE_ID, STATE, STATUS_ID, IMAGE_ID, REMIND_RINGTONE) "
                        + "VALUES (\'"
                        + data.getStringExtra("remind_name")
                        + "\',\'"
                        + data.getStringExtra("remind_description")
                        + "\', "
                        + data.getLongExtra("remind_timestamp", 0)
                        + ", 1, "
                        + data.getIntExtra("remind_state", 1)
                        + ", 1,"
                        + data.getIntExtra("image_id", 1)
                        + ",\'"
                        + data.getStringExtra("remind_ringtone") + "\'" +
                        ")";
```

I want to see the complete string, even without data. For example above:

```
"INSERT INTO REMINDERS (NAME, DESCRIPTION, REMIND_TIMESTAMP, REMIND_TYPE_ID, STATE, STATUS_ID, IMAGE_ID, REMIND_RINGTONE) VALUES ('data.getStringExtra("remind_name")', 'data.getStringExtra("remind_description")', data.getLongExtra("remind_timestamp", 0), 1, data.getIntExtra("remind_state", 1), 1, data.getIntExtra("image_id", 1), 'data.getStringExtra("remind_ringtone")')"
```

I need this to check commas in SQL queries.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use debugger to check values of variables at some point or LogCat to print out the values into LogCat console.

Comment: I hope you'll get your answer but even so I think you could take a look at http://www.jooq.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- set a breakpoint at the specific line
- start your app in debug mode and proceed until it halts at the breakpoint
- select the string and press ctrl+shif+i (inspect)